# How to upload image using apollo iOS client?

Tags: android, ios, swift, graphql, apollo-client

I am having a problem with uploading an image in ios apollo client. after I upload an image I get a **GraphQlError "createReadStream is not a function"**.
I could not figure out what has gone wrong?
**Mutation**

```
mutation UploadPhoto($input: UploadPhotoInput){
  uploadClientPhoto(input: $input){
    photo
  }
}
```

**Type Detail**

```
type UploadPhotoInput {
photo: Upload
}
type UploadPhotoResponse {
photo: String
}
```

**Following code is not working**

```
class Network {
  static let shared = Network()

  private lazy var networkTransport = HTTPNetworkTransport(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.10.29:5001/graphql")!, session: .init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default))

  private(set) lazy var apolloCient = ApolloClient(networkTransport: networkTransport)
}
```

**Upload image**

```
if let data = singlePhoto.image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
          let name = UUID().uuidString
          let file = GraphQLFile(fieldName: "\(name)", originalName: "\(name).png",mimeType: "image/png" ,data: data)

          let uploadInput = UploadPhotoInput(photo: file.originalName)
          let uploadMutation = UploadPhotoMutation(input: uploadInput)

          Network.shared.apolloCient.upload(operation: uploadMutation, context: nil, files: [file]) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let success):
              print(success.data)
            case .failure(let error):
              print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
          }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds frustrating. I've heard of similar issues with other networking clients, though.

Sounds like `apolloCient.upload` won't send a [GraphQL Multipart Request](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).

Looks like [this blog post](https://blog.apollographql.com/file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-5db2f3f60675) covers exactly how to set this up - even including an example repo made for React Native.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: How did you upload an image ?